# Extracting .7z file with Unrar.exe and command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, 7-zip, extract, winrar

With `WinRar.exe` 5.00 we can extract a `.7z` file. (with right click on a file and extract it)
but with `Unrar.exe` 5.00 and the following command line

```
C:\Program Files\WinRAR>unrar x "C:\Users\Mohammad\Downloads\somefile.7z"
```

I get the following message:

```
UNRAR 5.00 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2013 Alexander Roshal

C:\Users\Mohammad\Downloads\somefile.7z is not RAR archive
No files to extract
```

How can we extract `.7z` files with `Unrar.exe` with command line?

Answer (score 4):

`Winrar` supports a lot of file types ([source](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_archiver.htm)) and is a utility that supports more than just unarchiving:

> WinRAR provides complete support for RAR and ZIP archives and is able to unpack CAB, ARJ, LZH, TAR, GZ, ACE, UUE, BZ2, JAR, ISO, 7Z, XZ, Z archives.

Whereas `unrar` is only an unarchiver specifically for `rar` files.

You should be able to use `Winrar` to extract `7z` archives though:

```
winrar.exe x c:\file.7z
```

Note:  I am away from my windows box to verify, but that should do it.

Comment: I tested, but the following error has occurred for each file : `!   C:\Users\Mohammad\Downloads\somefile.7z: Cannot open simefile.jar`

Comment: Sounds like a separate issue, what command exactly are you entering? It's either bad flags or perhaps a corrupt archive (in which case you can check the hash if the download source provides it).